# HttpWebRequest: The operation has timed out

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, timeout, httpwebrequest

I have an MVC application hosted on Azure (PaaS) and for each incoming request it performs a call to an endpoint. I'm getting sometimes the following error: *the operation has timed out* but at endpoint side (even if i don't have visibility of what happens there) they say that they are not receiving those specific calls.
My MVC application has the following property set in the Global.asax file:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 64;
```

in order to avoid issues i'm setting that at each call, as it follows:

```
HttpWebRequest _WebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                            _WebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = connectionLimit;
_WebRequest.Proxy = null;
_WebRequest.Timeout = timeout;
_WebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;
_WebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
_WebRequest.UserAgent = UserAgent;
_WebRequest.Method = "POST";
_WebRequest.ContentType = contentType;
_WebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
_WebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
_WebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
_WebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
_WebRequest.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
_WebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
_WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
_WebRequest.Referer = referer;

byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
_WebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (Stream requestStream = _WebRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

using (WebResponse _webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)_WebRequest.GetResponse()) {
using (Stream dataStream = _webResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream)){
response = reader.ReadToEnd();
}}
```

i also enabled application insight on Azure side for my application but i cannot get any specific error apart from the timeout

i also tried setting my timeout to a very short value and retrying right after the error the call: in that case the second call is fine, so i'm wondering why the first call is sometimes failing

Comment: Please check if [230 seconds timeout](https://github.com/davidebbo/davidebbo.github.io/issues/48) limitation for request causes the issue.

Comment: No it isn't. Actually i tried setting a real small timeout (2 sec.) and after getting the error, if i retry right after the call is fine

Comment: **UPDATE** i was able to track the client / server request / response using FIDDLER and the strange scenario is that: the client sends the request and until the timeout is generated, no response is tracked on FIDDLER but as soon as the timeout is generated on FIDDLER i can see the correct response